# Android: associating an app with a file extension causes a new copy to start

Tags: android

I have arranged for my app to start when a file with the correct extension is chosen in a file manager. I have this in my manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kmz" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and in OnCreate() I call this method, to tell the app what to do with the chosen file:

```
private void associateFile()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN))
    {
        // this is a normal start, not a file manager start
       return;
    }
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    String filePath = FileLoader.LoadFile(this, uri);
    processFile(filePath);
}
```

and it all works fine....until I use the file manager method to start when the app is already running. This causes another copy to start, giving disastrous results with background tasks.

So how to I catch the fact that the app is already running, and just gracefully exit the second attempt at opening, with perhaps an appropriate message to the user? I have tried

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> taskInfo = am.getAppTasks();
```

to see if the app is already running, but the count of `taskInfo` is always one, not two as I would expect for the second attempt at opening.

Comment: "This causes another copy to start" -- it causes another instance of your activity to start. "giving disastrous results with background tasks" -- that suggests that you have some architectural problems, leading to bugs in your app code. "but the count of procInfos with my package name is always one" -- there is only one process, because there is only one instance of your app. An activity is not an app.

Comment: I suspect I do have architectural problems! Maybe solving this bug will sort them out.... sorry for my mixup of app/activity; I have now  edited that section of my question.

Comment: "but the count of taskInfo is always one, not two as I would expect for the second attempt at opening" -- just because another activity is being opened does not imply that a new task is being created.

Comment: I have found a solution (see above edit) but it uses a deprecated method. If I can find an alternative I'll post the method as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a much experimentation I have arrived at the following, using a new 'ParentActivity' to control what happens:

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
Intent parentIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    String filePath = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);
    parentIntent = getIntent();
    if (parentIntent.getAction() == null)
    {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    Uri uri = parentIntent.getData();
    if (uri != null)
        filePath = FileLoader.LoadFile(this, uri);

    // find out if MainActivity is already running
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
    for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks) {
        String strTask = String.valueOf(task.getTaskInfo().baseActivity);
        if (strTask.contains("MainActivity") && filePath != null)
        {
            // MainActivity already running while file manager used to select another file
            // tell MainActivity what file to deal with
            Intent fileIntent = new Intent("openFile");
            fileIntent.putExtra("openFile", filePath);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(fileIntent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
    // we need to start a new MainActivity
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    if (filePath != null)
    {
        //new start from file (chosen from file manager)
        mainIntent.putExtra("startWithFile",filePath);
    }
    startActivity (mainIntent);
    finish();
  }
}
```

I still don't understand *why* it works. In the loop checking the tasks, there is only ever *one* task found. So in the case of the app being started 'normally' (not from a file manager) the task info relates to ParentActivity, as expected. When the app is already running and the file manager used used to start a new instance, I would expect to see two tasks in this list: ParentActivity (for the new one) and MainActivity for the existing one. But there's only one task, MainActivity. What's happened to ParentActivity in the task list?

@CommonsWare, apologies if I haven't used the correct terminology in this analysis. I hope you (and others) get the gist.